# Django grappelli adding custom js to change_form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I try to add my custom javascript to some change_form templates. 
Before having installed Grappelli, I could do that by extending 
change_form.html of admin and creating sub folders under the templates 
with my module names.

For example my tree hireachy was like :

```
+templates 
++admin_copies 
+++change_form.html (I have added extra js blocks) 
++admin 
+++employer 
++++employer 
+++++change_form.html 
++++employer_new 
+++++change_form.html
```

As you understand I have a model named "Employer". I can add my custom 
js methods under the change_form.html files. 
However, this kind of inheritance cause javascript/breadcrumbs 
problems with Grappelli. 
How can I add simply my custom javascript functions for each model 
separetly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of `ModelAdmin`, and define the custom js in its `Media` class.

**`admin.py`, in the same folder as the `models.py` that has `Employer`:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Employer

class EmployerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("js/custom.js",) # This paths are appended to your MEDIA_URL setting

admin.site.register(Employer, EmployerAdmin)
```

[Read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions)